# No display of any angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material in the component but I can't see a thing!
I put mat-selecet, mat-table, date-picker.
I only see when I hover over it the corsur is changing and after clicking it's suddenly appear.
There are no comments at all.
I added the app.module, component.ts and the component.html.

component.html:

```
<head >
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="main" style="direction: rtl">
  
<img class="logo" src="../assets/images/volta_logo.png"> 
 

  <div class="select-space">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>work center</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let workSpace of workSpaces" [value]="workSpace.value">
          {{workSpace.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="choose-date">
  <h5>תאריך:</h5>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="Frompicker">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="Frompicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #Frompicker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <h5>date:</h5>
      <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="Topicker">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="Topicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #Topicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

      <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
            The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
    
      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

  </div>
  
 
</body>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatSelectModule  } from '@angular/material';

interface workSpace {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
]


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  
})



export class AppComponent {
  workSpaces: workSpace[] = [
    {value: 'space-0', viewValue: 'space1'},
    {value: 'space-1', viewValue: 'space2'},
    {value: 'space-2', viewValue: 'space3'}
  ];
  
  title = 'work';
}
```

app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatSelectModule  } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';







@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTableModule 
    
      
  ],
  exports: [ MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete this class:

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

and try to move declarations in your **AppComponent** class.

Comment: Why?  These are the headres for the table... The all materials are not properly display...

Comment: Are they used in index.html? Or why you have header and body tags? Because if they are, move them in a separate component. Styles are loaded only after the app was initialized. What do you mean by **component.html**?

Comment: I moved them. I looked over the imports... I think it's ok but still I can't see angular material only when I hover over it